# SpEL getValue() function slows over time

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, spring-el

I am trying to evaluate certain expressions which are doing comparison of two dates and then adding values in some fields as result.

e.g., `[${Submission Date} != null] ? ([${Submission Date} > ${Due Date}]` .. then `sum(${30},${83030},${4040},${83040})`

while I restart my `tomcat(version: 8.5.24)`, I get the result from `SpelExpression.getValue()` function in like 2 seconds, but whenever I resubmit the same `request( SpelExpression.getValue()` is called again ), the time increases from 2 to 4 to 5 to 6 to.....and it keeps on increasing.

In one of the production servers, I found the response from this function coming in 10 minutes and when I restarted the tomcat, everything just ran fine for first few requests.
After applying logs, I came to know that this `getValue()` function is the culprit.

I am using Spring 4 with java 7.

Any leads as to why this function slows down over time?

**Following is the expression:**

```
@expressionEvaluatorService.evaluateSubExpression(#expr1,#params,#entityContext,#errorConditions,#entityFields) ? (@expressionEvaluatorService.evaluateSubExpression(#expr2,#params,#entityContext,#errorConditions,#entityFields) ? T(com.sirionlabs.service.ExpressionEvaluatorServiceImpl).duration(#F1047,#med41806) :  T(com.sirionlabs.service.ExpressionEvaluatorServiceImpl).duration(#F1046,#med41806) ) :  (@expressionEvaluatorService.evaluateSubExpression(#expr3,#params,#entityContext,#errorConditions,#entityFields) ? T(com.sirionlabs.service.ExpressionEvaluatorServiceImpl).duration(#F1047,#med41806): 0)
```

**and context is:**

```
0 = {HashMap$Entry@24411} "ssd41780" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:57 IST 2017"
 1 = {HashMap$Entry@24412} "F100118" -> "20230111"
 2 = {HashMap$Entry@24413} "F100117" -> "20230125"
 3 = {HashMap$Entry@24414} "ssd41755" -> "Wed Dec 20 17:09:55 IST 2017"
 4 = {HashMap$Entry@24415} "F100113" -> "0"
 5 = {HashMap$Entry@24416} "entity" -> "ChildDNO[dnoStatus=<null>,dnoType=Disaster Recovery/Business Continuity,dno=<null>,pageRefrences=[com.sirionlabs.model.PageReference@26c6083],performanceStatus=<null>,weekTypeObject=com.sirionlabs.bentity.admin.IdName@31086ff9,clientOwner=<null>,vendorOwner=<null>,escalationOwner=<null>,type=<null>,clause=<null>,sharedWith=<null>,sharedBy=<null>,responsibility=com.sirionlabs.bentity.admin.IdName@27df7a,revisedDueDate=<null>,currency=Currency[linkContractCurrencies=<null>,masterRegions=<null>,value=<null>,integrationSystem=<null>,oldSystemId=<null>,dynamicMetadata=<null>,dynamicMetadataJson=<null>,parentEntityTypeId=<null>,actualParentEntityId=<null>,actualParentEntityTypeId=<null>,parentEntityId=<null>,rootInfo=<null>,draft=<null>,privateCommunication=<null>,entitySpecificType=<null>,blocked=false,parentEntity=<null>,sourceEntity=<null>,entityContract=<null>,entityRelation=<null>,autoCreateEntities=<null>,entityId=<null>,currentFeatureVersion=<null>,entityType=<null>,actio
 6 = {HashMap$Entry@24417} "ssd41759" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:28 IST 2017"
 7 = {HashMap$Entry@24418} "F100323" -> "73"
 8 = {HashMap$Entry@24419} "msd41755" -> "Thu Dec 21 00:00:00 IST 2017"
 9 = {HashMap$Entry@24420} "F100327" -> "20221214"
 10 = {HashMap$Entry@24421} "med41788" -> "Thu Jan 18 14:20:40 IST 2018"
 11 = {HashMap$Entry@24422} "sed41780" -> "Thu Jan 18 14:18:14 IST 2018"
 12 = {HashMap$Entry@24423} "t41780" -> " size = 58"
 13 = {HashMap$Entry@24424} "ssd41788" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:41:18 IST 2017"
 14 = {HashMap$Entry@24425} "med41780" -> "Thu Jan 18 14:18:14 IST 2018"
 15 = {HashMap$Entry@24426} "sed41788" -> "Thu Jan 18 14:20:40 IST 2018"
 16 = {HashMap$Entry@24427} "med41806" -> "2018-01-18T14:20:41.614Z"
 17 = {HashMap$Entry@24428} "F119" -> "null"
 18 = {HashMap$Entry@24429} "F100195" -> "20170101"
 19 = {HashMap$Entry@24430} "F100166" -> 
 20 = {HashMap$Entry@24431} "F11720" -> "null"
 21 = {HashMap$Entry@24432} "med41759" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:28 IST 2017"
 22 = {HashMap$Entry@24433} "F100122" -> "false"
 23 = {HashMap$Entry@24434} "t41788" -> " size = 58"
 24 = {HashMap$Entry@24435} "sed41755" -> "Wed Dec 20 17:09:55 IST 2017"
 25 = {HashMap$Entry@24436} "F1047" -> "Wed Dec 14 23:59:59 IST 2022"
 26 = {HashMap$Entry@24437} "sed41759" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:28 IST 2017"
 27 = {HashMap$Entry@24438} "msd41788" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:41:18 IST 2017"
 28 = {HashMap$Entry@24439} "med41755" -> "Thu Dec 21 00:00:00 IST 2017"
 29 = {HashMap$Entry@24440} "F1046" -> "Thu Jan 18 23:59:59 IST 2018"
 30 = {HashMap$Entry@24441} "entityContext" -> 
 31 = {HashMap$Entry@24442} "msd41780" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:57 IST 2017"
 32 = {HashMap$Entry@24443} "F11036" -> "null"
 33 = {HashMap$Entry@24444} "errorConditions" -> " size = 0"
 34 = {HashMap$Entry@24445} "F1060" -> "null"
 35 = {HashMap$Entry@24446} "t41759" -> " size = 1"
 36 = {HashMap$Entry@24447} "expr3" -> "${Due Date} <'current_date'"
 37 = {HashMap$Entry@24448} "F1023" -> "null"
 38 = {HashMap$Entry@24449} "expr1" -> "${Submission Date} != null"
 39 = {HashMap$Entry@24450} "F1024" -> "null"
 40 = {HashMap$Entry@24451} "expr2" -> "${Submission Date} > ${Due Date}"
 41 = {HashMap$Entry@24452} "t41755" -> " size = 1"
 42 = {HashMap$Entry@24453} "ssd41766" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:44 IST 2017"
 43 = {HashMap$Entry@24454} "med41766" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:44 IST 2017"
 44 = {HashMap$Entry@24455} "sed41766" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:44 IST 2017"
 45 = {HashMap$Entry@24456} "F1156" -> "null"
 46 = {HashMap$Entry@24457} "F1157" -> "null"
 47 = {HashMap$Entry@24458} "F1158" -> "Wed Dec 14 23:59:59 IST 2022"
 48 = {HashMap$Entry@24459} "t41766" -> " size = 1"
 49 = {HashMap$Entry@24460} "msd41766" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:44 IST 2017"
 50 = {HashMap$Entry@24461} "params" -> " size = 48"
 51 = {HashMap$Entry@24462} "msd41759" -> "Fri Dec 22 10:40:28 IST 2017"
 52 = {HashMap$Entry@24463} "F417" -> "null"
 53 = {HashMap$Entry@24464} "entityFields" -> " size = 148"
 54 = {HashMap$Entry@24465} "F1061" -> "Thu Jan 18 23:59:59 IST 2018"
```

Comment: You need to show the exact expression and the context in which you are calling it as well as the types that are passed in.

Comment: @GaryRussell : I have updated the description, any help is highly appreciated. Do let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I seriously doubt it's SpEL that's slowing down; you need to show all your custom code too e.g. `evaluateSubExpression`. Have you tried profiling your application to see where the time is being spent?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately found a solution, there was a bug with the version of spring i was using 4.0.0.RELEASE, I upgraded it to 4.0.2 and it worked fine.